# best way to collect birthdays in google forms

Tags: user-experience

I need to collect birth dates in a  Google Form. In my first iteration I chose to format the question as a date, but the form pre-filled the year with 2017, which many users did not notice - ultimately causing yours truly extra work hunting chasing bad data. I took a survey from Google and they made the birth date three separate fields. What's the best way to collect a birth date?

Answer (score 0):

For birthdays (when you are going years back) the best way is to go as an inverted pyramid: First year, then month, lastly day.

UX-wise, for birth dates, it is better to use a `<select>` for each string (year, month, date) rather than using an `<input type="date">`